# certificate errors trying to create a virtualenv on old Ubuntu

Tags: python, certificates

On an old Ubuntu 8.04 (cannot upgrade yet) I need to create a Python virtualenv, install some packages and then my software.

I do get certificate errors:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlrd/: connection error:    
[Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate   routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib     
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlrd/ when looking for
download links for xlrd
```

so I cannot upgrade `pip` or `setuptools`, and have no luck finding how to update just the certificate (the system is old and cannot be update using `apt`).
The python installed is the latest `python-2.7` (I have to use `pip-2.7` and `virtualenv-2.7` in order not to get the old system versions that I don't want to touch).

How can I install appropriate certificates, or work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is use `easy_install` to downgrade `pip`:

```
easy_install-2.7 pip==1.2.1
```

I also downgraded `setuptools` to version 3.6, but a later version might work:

```
easy_install setuptools==3.6
```

After that you should be able to use pip-2.7 to update things for python-2.7

---

If you create a virtualenv after that and activate it, you will have the latest version of pip, which again will not install anything:

```
$ virtualenv-2.7 testvenv
$ source testenv/bin/activate
(testvenv) $ pip --version
pip 1.5.6
(testvenv) $ pip install ruamel.ordereddict
Downloading/unpacking ruamel.ordereddict
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  ...
```

So repeat the easy-install trick (it is not necessary to specify `pip-2.7` or `easy-install-2.7` within the activated virtualenv):

```
(testvenv) $ easy_install pip==1.2.1
....
(testvenv) $ pip install ruamel.ordereddict
Downloading/unpacking ruamel.ordereddict
   Downloading ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.6.tar.gz (47kB): 47kB downloaded
....
Successfully installed ruamel.ordereddict
Cleaning up...
(testvenv) $
```

Comment: Any special version of virtualenv I need use?

Comment: I am using the current (latest) version: virtualenv 1.11.6

Comment: Thanx a bunch, pip is installing in my virtualenv now.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz

tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz

cd pip-1.2.1

python setup.py install
```